# ¿Cómo abrir un archivo html desde una terminal Linux?

Tags: html, linux, ubuntu, terminal, google-chrome

He creado un archivo html de práctica y lo he guardado en una carpeta que cree desde Ubuntu.

Ya sé como abrir mi VSCode desde la terminal para poder editarlo pero, mi problema es como visualizar el trabajo final en Chrome.

Es decir, no conozco el comando para poder abrir mi archivo html en Chrome desde la terminal de Linux.

Si alguien me podría ayudar, se lo agradecería infinitamente.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: `x-www-browser http://dominio.tld` o `x-www-browser /ruta/al/archivo.html`

Answer (score 1):

Prueba `chromium-browser directorio/del/archivo`

Comment: Lo he intentado ahora pero, me sale que no encuentra el comando.

google-chrome: command not found

Comment: Tienes razón, dijiste que estas en Ubuntu...En Ubuntu se usa chromium, ya que chrome no es open source. Si lo tienes instalado, reemplaza `google-chrome` por `chromium-browser`.

Comment: Lo he intentado pero tampoco me funciono. Primero descargue lo descargue por que ni siquiera lo tenia, luego intente ingresar las lineas de comando que me pasaste reemplazando el google-chrome por chromium-browser pero, me sale el siguiente mensaje.

Command '/usr/bin/chromium-browser' requires the chromium snap to be installed.
Please install it with:

snap install chromium

Y lo intente de instalar pero tampoco pude.

Comment: ¿ Puedes abrir el crhorme fuera de la terminal?

Answer (score 1):

No se si he entendido bien tu pregunta, pero creo quieres ejecutar tu archivo html en un ubuntu. Abre el navegador y arrastralo. O con el botón derecho encima del archivo dile que lo ejecute con el navegador que tengas.
Otra opción es una extensión del VSCode que se llama live Server. Puedes ver los cambios directamente en el navegador tal y como vas guardando el código.
Para instalar el chromium prueba un sudo apt-get install chromium

Answer (score 1):

si quieres abrir un archivo, en este caso un html desde la terminal, intenta esto

```
chromium practica.html
```

en mi caso no tengo chrome sino chromium, si lo reemplazo por firefox funciona de igual manera.

tener en cuenta que el archivo esta dentro del directorio `/home`,  si esta en otra ubicacion indicar en ruta ejemplo `/dir1/dir2/practica.html`

el comando `pwd` puede ayudar

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Otra cosa que puedes intentar desde la terminal de Ubunto es > ***google-chrome index.html*** ese comando lo abrira de immediato. Se que es muy tarde pero mejor tarde que nunca jeje

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).